# PHP - How to Pass Value from Previous Textbox to Newly Created Row on the Same Page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm planning to use a form to register new Teacher (see image bellow). A teacher can assign to different classes to teach different subjects.

Is it possible to pass the value from textbox in Row1_Column1 (AAAA) to textbox in Row2_Column1 when a new row is created by clicking on button (+)?

I don't want the user to take pain in typing the same values in some of the textboxes - the values will be the same. Only [Subject Taught] and [Class Taught] columns might be different, so i want to leave those empty for every new row created.

[Sample Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq0Tc.png)

My code is as follows:

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  <!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <p><button class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="viewStaff">
     <i class="ace-icon fa fa-eye bigger-120"></i>
    View List</button>
   </p>
   <form method="post" id="insert_form">
    <span id="error"></span>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="staff_table">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Name (Initials)</th>
       <th>Username</th>
       <th>Password</th>
       <th>Role</th>
       <th>Class Assigned</th>
       <th>Subject Taught</th>
       <th>Class Taught</th>
       <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="space-24"></div>
    <div class="clearfix form-actions">

     <div class="center">
      <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit">
       <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check bigger-110"></i>
       Submit
      </button>

      &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <button class="btn" type="reset">
       <i class="ace-icon fa fa-undo bigger-110"></i>
       Reset
      </button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="initials[]" class="form-control initials" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="user_name[]" class="form-control user_name" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="password" name="password[]" class="form-control password" /></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="role[]" class="form-control role"><option value="">Select...</option><option value="admin">Admin</option><option value="form_master">Form Master</option><option value="staff">Staff</option></select></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="class_assigned[]" class="form-control class_assigned"><option value="">Select...</option><?php echo fill_class_box($conn); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="subject_taught[]" class="form-control subject_taught"><option value="">Select...</option><?php echo fill_subject_box($conn); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="class_taught[]" class="form-control class_taught"><option value="">Select...</option><?php echo fill_class_box($conn); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';

  $('#staff_table').append(html);
 });
 
 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });
 
 
$('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var error = '';
  $('.initials').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error = "<p>Please enter the required information</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  
  $('.user_name').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error = "<p>Please enter the required information</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.password').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error = "<p>Please enter the required information</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  
  $('.role').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error = "<p>Please enter the required information</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.class_assigned').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
       return true;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.subject_taught').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error = "<p>Please enter the required information</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.class_taught').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error = "<p>Please enter the required information</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  if(error == '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"staff_insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
     if(data == 'ok')
     {
      $('#staff_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Staff Details Saved</div>');
     }
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
  }
 });
 
});
</script>
```

And staff_insert.php

```
<?php
//staff_insert.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "studentsdatabase");
if(isset($_POST["initials"]))
{
 $initials = $_POST["initials"];
 $user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];
 $role = $_POST["role"];
 $class_assigned = $_POST["class_assigned"];
 $subject_taught = $_POST["subject_taught"];
 $class_taught = $_POST["class_taught"];

 $query = '';
 for($count = 0; $count<count($initials); $count++)
 {
  $initials_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $initials[$count]);
  $user_name_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $user_name[$count]);
  $password_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $password[$count]);
  $role_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $role[$count]);
  $class_assigned_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $class_assigned[$count]);
  $subject_taught_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $subject_taught[$count]);
  $class_taught_clean = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $class_taught[$count]);

  if($initials_clean != '' && $user_name_clean != '' && $password_clean != '' && $role_clean != '' && $class_assigned_clean != '' && $subject_taught_clean != '' && $class_taught_clean != '')
  {
   $query .= '
   INSERT INTO tbl_users(fullname, username, password, role, class_assigned, subject_taught, class_taught) 
   VALUES("'.$initials_clean.'", "'.$user_name_clean.'", "'.$password_clean.'", "'.$role_clean.'", "'.$class_assigned_clean.'", "'.$subject_taught_clean.'", "'.$class_taught_clean.'"); 
   ';
  }
 }
 if($query != '')
 {
  if(mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query))
  {
   echo 'ok';
  }
 }
}
?>
```

Please if you know of a better way, kindly help.

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

New Image [Please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSoWZ.png)

How can I manipulate the above jquery to make the `Name`, `Username`, `Password`, `Role` and `Class Assigned` appear for each row the remaining inputs `Subject Taught` and `Class Taught`?

Please help.

Comment: On form submit pass you mean?

Comment: Code snippets are for [client side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side) languages only (javascript), so you should put your code just as `code` not a snippet. That also applies to your question in some way as you have to ask yourself where the copy process should take place, on [server side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side) (PHP) or on clien side (javascript/jquery).

Comment: @clearshot66, No! not on form submit. On New row. when the green (plus sign) button is clicked.

Comment: @Sanxofon, thanks, I've corrected the snippets. I want the copy process to take place on client side before Submit

Comment: You can use jquery clone to copy the row with its values and append, then empty the text boxes you don't want values in on that copied row.

Comment: @FunkDoc, I don't know how. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some fields are not populated as no `server side` data can be retrived here. Bu you can see the example for the `Role` column.

Look for this part in the snippet:

```
  // Here is were you can do the conditional and copying part
  var last_row_role_sel_val = $('#staff_table tr:last td:nth-child(4) select option:selected').val();
  var last_row_role_sel_html = $('#staff_table tr:last td:nth-child(4) select option:selected').html();
  console.log('last_row_role_sel_val',last_row_role_sel_val);
  console.log('last_row_role_sel_html',last_row_role_sel_html);
```

And the replacement part

```
if (last_row_role_sel_val!=undefined && last_row_role_sel_val!="") {
  html += '<td><select name="role[]" class="form-control role"><option value="'+last_row_role_sel_val+'">'+last_row_role_sel_html+'</option></select></td>';
} else {
...
```

```js
//$( "b" ).clone().prependTo( "p" );
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  
  // Here is were you can do the conditional and copying part
  var last_5_rows_sel_val = [];
  var last_5_rows_sel_html = [];
  for (var i=1;i<=5;i++) {
    if (i>=4) {
    last_5_rows_sel_val.push($('#staff_table tr:last td:nth-child('+i+') select option:selected').val());
      last_5_rows_sel_html.push($('#staff_table tr:last td:nth-child('+i+') select option:selected').html());
    } else {
      last_5_rows_sel_val.push($('#staff_table tr:last td:nth-child('+i+') input').val());
      last_5_rows_sel_html.push('');
    }
  }
  if (last_5_rows_sel_val[0]!=undefined && last_5_rows_sel_val[0]!="") {
  
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="initials[]" class="form-control initials" value="'+last_5_rows_sel_val[0]+'" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="user_name[]" class="form-control user_name" value="'+last_5_rows_sel_val[1]+'" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="password" name="password[]" class="form-control password" value="'+last_5_rows_sel_val[2]+'" /></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="role[]" class="form-control role"><option value="'+last_5_rows_sel_val[3]+'">'+last_5_rows_sel_html[3]+'</option></select></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="class_assigned[]" class="form-control class_assigned"><option value="'+last_5_rows_sel_val[4]+'">'+last_5_rows_sel_html[4]+'</option></select></td>';
  
} else {
  
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="initials[]" class="form-control initials" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="user_name[]" class="form-control user_name" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="password" name="password[]" class="form-control password" /></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="role[]" class="form-control role"><option value="">Select...</option><option value="admin">Admin</option><option value="form_master">Form Master</option><option value="staff">Staff</option></select></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="class_assigned[]" class="form-control class_assigned"><option value="">Select...</option><?php echo fill_class_box($conn); ?></select></td>';
}
  html += '<td><select name="subject_taught[]" class="form-control subject_taught"><option value="">Select...</option><?php echo fill_subject_box($conn); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="class_taught[]" class="form-control class_taught"><option value="">Select...</option><?php echo fill_class_box($conn); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span></button></td></tr>';

  $('#staff_table').append(html);
 });
 
 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });
 
 
$('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var error = '';
  $('.initials').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error = "<p>Please enter the required information</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  
  $('.user_name').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error = "<p>Please enter the required information</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.password').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error = "<p>Please enter the required information</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  
  $('.role').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error = "<p>Please enter the required information</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.class_assigned').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
       return true;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.subject_taught').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error = "<p>Please enter the required information</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.class_taught').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error = "<p>Please enter the required information</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  if(error == '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"staff_insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
     if(data == 'ok')
     {
      $('#staff_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Staff Details Saved</div>');
     }
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
  }
 });
 
});
```

```css
table,th,tr,td,div,p {
border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
  <!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <p><button class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="viewStaff">
     <i class="ace-icon fa fa-eye bigger-120"></i>
    View List</button>
   </p>
   <form method="post" id="insert_form">
    <span id="error"></span>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="staff_table">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Name (Initials)</th>
       <th>Username</th>
       <th>Password</th>
       <th>Role</th>
       <th>Class Assigned</th>
       <th>Subject Taught</th>
       <th>Class Taught</th>
       <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span></button></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="space-24"></div>
    <div class="clearfix form-actions">

     <div class="center">
      <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit">
       <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check bigger-110"></i>
       Submit
      </button>

      &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <button class="btn" type="reset">
       <i class="ace-icon fa fa-undo bigger-110"></i>
       Reset
      </button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

UPDATED!!

Comment: that was awesome! It works. However,  what do you think I can do to make others populate? I really need those. Thanks

Comment: I am thinking: What if I have the first FIVE inputs (Name, Username, Password, Role and Class Assigned) stay separately... (not part of the rows), how can I make that user appear in the Table for the number of rows of other TWO columns (Subject Taught and Class Taught)?

Comment: You could do that also... I've updated the snippet for all 5 first fields.

Comment: WOW! @Sanxofon, you're such a Genius! Can I hug you pls? THANK YOU SO MUCH. What a perfect solution! I wish I can give UP VOTE - need 1 more reputation, I do, before I can do that.